# index.php:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token: error message in Ci

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

In my Javascript code after the line below:

> url: ....../Misc-2/Ci-TodoList/index.php/home/jsonAddData,

I am getting the following error:

> index.php:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: <?php echo site_url("home/jsonAddData"); ?>,
            data: dataString,
            json: {title_posted: true},
            success: function(data){
            if(data.title_posted == true) { // true means data was successfully posted.
                $("#success").append("Success");
            } else if(data.title_posted == false) { // false means data failed to post.
                $("#success").append('Failure');
            }
          }
       });
    }
});

      }
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm pretty positive after a few debugging tricks that index.php:13 is referring to my PHP script. One of the things it was doing was saying that when I was loading the url helper, it said that that was causing the error. Then I autoloaded the url helper and now it's saying line 13 is causing the error, but line 13 is only a mysql select query as you can determine below:

```
<?php
class home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index() {
        $data = array();
        $data['lists'] = $this->displayList();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
    function displayList() {
        $str = '';
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $b = '<input name="completed" type="checkbox" />';
            $a = $row->title . "<br>";
            $str .= $b.$a;
        }
        return $str;
    }
    function jsonAddData() {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        header('Content-type:application/json');
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO data (title) VALUES ('$title')");
        if($query) return json_encode(array('title_posted' => true));
        else return json_encode(array('title_posted' => false));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Any ideas to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you positive that is the right index.php file?

Comment: It can't be... Post the file named "index.php" Lines 3 - 23 should do.

Comment: Unexpexted token is a js error. Are you seeing that in firebug? Your json may have dodgey characters in it

Comment: You're also not setting your headers in the correct CI way by the way. See the output class

Comment: @BenSwinburne yes I'm seeing it in the Chrome Javascript Console... and thanks for that tidbit of info. I'll most def read up on the output class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting JS error so PHP syntax is not the culprit. :)

Wrap `<?php echo site_url("home/jsonAddData"); ?>` in double quotations (I mean `""`). Also you have other syntax errors, proper indenting can save your time in the future.

Here is the solved version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "<?php echo site_url("home/jsonAddData"); ?>",
                data: dataString,
                json: {title_posted: true},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.title_posted == true) { // true means data was successfully posted.
                        $("#success").append("Success");
                    } else if(data.title_posted == false) { // false means data failed to post.
                        $("#success").append('Failure');
                    }
               }
          });
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man.... this is a big help. What exactly was I doing wrong though? was it just the single quotations? Or was it something else too?

Comment: You are most welcome, there was a quotation issue and you also messed up with brackets, specially in this two   `}    });` . No worries, cheers :)